# Calling HttpRequest::getRawRequestMessage() without send()

Tags: php, httprequest

I am trying to call `getRawRequestMessage()` to get the raw HTTP content of the request described by a `HttpRequest` object, but I notice it always returns an empty string if I don't call `send()` first which kind of defeats my purpose (I want to send the data through other means than the HttpRequest's own send() method).

Is there any other way to convert a `HttpRequest` object to its raw string equivalent?

To give more context: I'm working with a complex class that builds a `HttpRequest` object and sends requests through it and I want to add a new mode to the class that will work through raw sockets instead. The request is already built in the `HttpRequest` object and I would like to not have to parse the object manually to generate the HTTP message.

Comment: Is there a reason you're building an `HttpRequest` if you're not going to use it? (I suspect, in light of the difficulty extracting the raw message from this object, that there's a simpler way to construct the message to begin with.)

Comment: Maybe I should clarify the question: if you have control over the class generating the HttpRequest, how much more difficult could it be to direct your parameters to http_build_query (or similar) instead?

Comment: There is a lot of code already written to send the required data to `HttpRequest`. It's not just query params that I can easily generate with `http_build_query` and the like. There are various headers, request body, etc. I don't want to duplicate all that code. Plus, there's a lot of logic inside `HttpRequest` to correctly parse all that data into a valid HTTP request. I don't want to rewrite that either.